# How to create a Ruby array slice which shares the same instance of the original array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

So that if the slice gets changed, the original array will also change?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[1, 2]
b[0] = 42 # due to COW, only b changes, a remains unchanged
```

Expected result: when run `b[0] = 42`, `a[1]` will also changed to 42.

Edit: Is there any library for this?

For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ArraySlice.new(a, 1, 2)
... # changes in b will be reflected in a
```

P.S. I'm new to Ruby. What I want is basically the same as Java's [ByteBuffer.slice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice()). Sometimes this is useful because we can avoid creating too many new array object.

Comment: Don't continue a sentence from the title into the main text. Duplication between the title and the text is fine.

Comment: I don’t see any reason to close this question. It’s asked appropriately and clear.

Comment: @sawa COW means Copy On Write, I found it here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/33950

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like that in either the core library or the standard libraries and I also don't know of any third-party libraries. You will have to roll your own, something like this maybe:

```
class ArraySlice
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(ary=[], start=0, length=ary.size - start)
    self.ary, self.start, self.length = ary, start, length
  end

  def [](*args)
    return ArraySlice.new(ary, args.first + start, args.last) if args.size == 2
    return ArraySlice.new(ary, args.first.begin + start, if args.first.exclude_end? then args.first.end - args.first.begin - 1 else args.first.end - args.first.begin end) if args.first.is_a?(Range)
    ary[args.first + start]
  end

  def []=(*args, value)
    return ary[args.first + start, length] = value if args.size == 2
    return ary[Range.new(args.first.begin + start, args.first.end + start, args.first.exclude_end?)] = value if args.first.is_a?(Range)
    ary[args.first + start] = value
  end

  def each(&blk)
    ary[start, length].each(&blk)
  end

  # and so on …

  private

  attr_accessor :ary, :start, :length
end

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ArraySlice.new(a, 1, 2)
b[0] = 42
a[1] # => 42
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Although a and b reference the same objects the references themselves are distinct. So updating one reference won't update the other. If you change the underlying object instead they do operate as you expect.

```
a = [{}, {}, {}]
b = a[1,2]

b[0][:copy?] = true

puts a.inspect
#[{}, {:copy?=>true}, {}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` creates a new array. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D):

> Returns a new array populated with the given objects.

Since it is a copy, changing the new array will not change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = a[1, 2]
b.each{|str| str << "!"}

p a # => ["a", "b!", "c!"]
```

Does not work for immutable objects like integers.